# Converting date to this format

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, datetime

I have a date in this format:

```
   24-12-2010 // DAY - MONTH - YEAR
```

I need to get it in this format:

```
   1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z // The Z is for the TimeZone I think.
```

Check this link out:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html

The above link is the way I need the date.

I am using PHP now, so this needs to be with PHP.
How can I convert these dates the easiest way?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

That is an ISO8601 format date; the following is what you want.

```
gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($date_value));
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this way because it is error prone. Better provide the input format yourself, and use DateTime::W3C for the output format.

Comment: If the input format is fixed and predictable it is reliable (e.g. from a DB). If the input format is coming from the user then it is always necessary to reparse it.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like that:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($myDate);
$formatted = $dateTime->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.z\Z");
```

The mentioned solution with:

```
$dateTime->format(DateTime::W3C);
$dateTime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

does return strings like:

```
2012-11-28T17:21:11+0100
```

which cannot be parsed, at least with newer Solr versions.

I wouldn't use gmdate if you need to support timezones. The DateTime implementation is well done, and is also available for functional programming.

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: `z` is "The day of the year (starting from 0) 0 through 365" - is this format correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types) class

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime.setDate(24, 12, 2010);

$output = $dateTime.format(DateTime::W3C);

// Output now is your date in W3C format.
```

Comment: Unfort this doesn't work with Solr. The output would be "2012-11-28T17:21:11+0100" which is wrong.

Comment: Also . notation is not existent in PHP.

Comment: @Christian Actually, it is used for concatenation. :P

Answer (score 0):

use the date ( string $format [, int $timestamp ] ) function of php! 
In second paramter use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php to get the timestamp from strings

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strtotime('24-12-2010');
$new_date = gmDate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.z\Z",$date);
```